# AWS Cognito in JavaEE for Auth

Tags: jax-rs, amazon-cognito, java-ee-7

***What's the best way to check if a user is authenticated, and pull her identity & roles for authorization decisions, via AWS cognito within a JAX-RS WebService environment?***

I am thinking about the following architecture on AWS:

- Server Side: Java EE backend REST-ful services, which requiring authenticated access
- Client Side: A variety of apps (mobile / webapps / etc) that consume the services via HTTP

Not wanting to reinvent security, I am thinking about how to integrate AWS Cognito with the JavaEE backend. I am used to Keycloak which provides an AuthAdapter via ServletFilter handling all the integration with the OAuth2 Token Endpoint and leaving me as a developer to work with Java Security Mechanisms.